# how to test/mock and API Rest genatered via CRUDRepository?

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, automated-tests

I want to generate automated tests for an REST API.
My controller has a method that already get a list from a DB and 
genarete a JSON:

```
@Path("/mrp/banco")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getFromDB() {
        try {
            List<MRP> list = new LinkedList<MRP>();
            list = repository.select();
            LOGGER.info("tamanho da lista/tuplas : " + list.size());
            return Response.ok().entity(list).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I have no Idea of how to write a junit test. Even with mock.
Can someone help me?

Thanks

PS.: My repo:

```
public interface MRPRepository extends CrudRepository<MRP,Long>{    
    @Query("SELECT m FROM MRP m WHERE QTD_SALDO_PROGRAMAR > 0 "
            + "AND FLAG_PLANEJADO = 0 AND FLAG_CANCELADO = 0"
            + "AND FLAG_ATENDIDO=0" )
    List<MRP> select();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a simulator database, for example h2 database when you are running tests.

Comment: In my test, I really want to consume the API and set an assert which must test it

Comment: You can use TestRestTemplate

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you question, you can use RestAssured for http testing.

```
Response response = RestAssured.given()
            .baseUri("http://localhost:8080")
            .get("/mrp/banco");

    response.then().statusCode(200);
    List<MRP> mrps = Arrays.asList(response.as(MRP[].class));
    // assert anything you want
```